# Stop Valuechanges of formcontrol and the formgroup

Tags: angular

I have a formgroup which has a formcontrol. I have subscribed the valuechanges event of both formgroup and formcontrol.With a button click i would like to disable and reset value of formcontrol without firing valuechanges so i have used `emitEvent:false` which doesnot fire the valuechanges of the formcontrol but valuechanges of the formgroup is fired.I have a sample plunker demo here https://plnkr.co/edit/cN2wROc7o16w52ZEPZgH?p=preview .Is this expected behavior or an issue.Can somebody guide me

```
  ResetAndDisable(){
    this.ParentGroup.controls['test'].reset(null,{emitEvent:false});
    this.ParentGroup.controls['test'].disable({emitEvent:false});
 }
 Enable(){
    this.ParentGroup.controls['test'].enable({emitEvent:false});
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a combination of `emitEvent:false` and `onlySelf:true`, where **[`onlySelf:true`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue)** ...

> If `onlySelf` is true, this change will only affect the validation of this FormControl and not its parent component. This defaults to `false`.

So what you can do is then:

```ts
ResetAndDisable(){
  this.ParentGroup.get('test').reset(null,{onlySelf:true, emitEvent:false});
  this.ParentGroup.get('test').disable({onlySelf:true, emitEvent:false});
}
Enable(){
  this.ParentGroup.get('test').enable({onlySelf:true,  emitEvent:false});
}
```