# Reactive formcontrol triggers Change Detection

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

Reactive `FormControl` element triggers `ChangeDetection` whenever the input value is changed. I have added `OnPush` strategy but still it runs `ChangeDetection`,

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-input',
  templateUrl: './server-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-input.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

The `FormControl` directive is the one that triggers `ChangeDetection`. How do i stop running the `ChangeDetection` when the input changes?

```js
serverName: FormControl = new FormControl();
```

Here is my [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-8scuv6-dym6sc?file=projects%2Fserver-state%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) on StackBlitz.

**Note: One thing to note here is if you click on the button, the ngDocheck is called so I have used event manager to stop the change detection.**

Comment: It seems like the internal implementation triggers the OnPush change detection. At this point, it'd be better to change how you are trying to implement your solution.

Comment: https://indepth.dev/posts/1131/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article

Comment: Please read the article, @Robin Dijkhof is the right answer:
https://indepth.dev/posts/1131/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article

Comment: You have to understand when there is no fomcontrol assigned then there is no change detection.

Answer (score 2):

`ngDoCheck` does always run. No matter what strategy you use. See https://indepth.dev/posts/1131/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article and [Why do we need `ngDoCheck`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643389/why-do-we-need-ngdocheck)

I can't see any reason why you'd want to know when, how are why change-detection has run. If you want to do something on change, just use a setter on your input:

```
_name: string;
get name(): string{
    return this._name;
}
@Input() set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
    this.doUpdateSomething();
}
```

Comment: I have added a button on the parent component and clicked on it, then the ngDocheck ran on the child component but when I have handled the click event outside ngZone then the nDocheck of the child component did not run. This experiment proves that ngDoCheck dont always run by default

Comment: You have to understand when there is no form-control assigned then there the ngDocheck is not run in the child component

Answer (score 1):

I've forked and updated your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/child-component-2bstm4?file=app/app.component.ts

```js
  ngOnInit() {    
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => (
      this.serverName = new FormControl(),
      this.cd.detach()
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: In contrast to TypeScript Developers, Angular Developers also thought about what would happen if we set a fire and turn off the fire alarm. If you look at the ChangeDetectorRef API, you find that they have thought every possibility. "Detach" is one of them: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef . All of these steps can be initiated manually, which in the best case scenario should work automatically.

Comment: I award the bounty to this answer. But this did not work on my app.

Comment: StackBlitz works with zones, where `this.cd.detach()` is specified as a parameter. In your real app, you have to place it before creating the form.

Comment: here is my stackblitz -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-8scuv6-dym6sc?file=projects%2Fserver-state%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I tried already with cd.detach, Its not working.

Comment: Did you intentionally used `this.cdr.detectChanges();` ?

Comment: Yes because that display component has an on-push strategy and when the observable emits I have to call detect changes method

Comment: I'm afraid that after everything is running asynchronously, they'll get in each other's way. You have to reorganize the workflow in your app. I always use async-await to be sure of the execution order.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent angular from running the change detection each time the user interacts with the input field you should detach the change detector.
You need to inject the ChangeDetectorRef and call its detach method

```js
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cd.detach();
  }
```

The change detection will no longer be automatically run for this component and its children.
When you need to trigger a change detection you can call the detectChanges method on the ChangeDetectorRef.

For exemple this will trigger the change detection every 5 seconds.

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cd.detach();
    setInterval(() => this.cd.detectChanges(), 5000);
  }
```

Comment: This is not relevant at all.

Answer (score -1):

In the link mentioned below, there is an option to disable change detection on form control

[disable form control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653231/stop-valuechanges-of-formcontrol-and-the-formgroup)